# Mapping bluetooth controller in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, bluetooth, controller

I am thinking of buying a bluetooth controller. Somthing like [this](https://www.banggood.com/Wireless-Bluetooth-Gamepad-VR-BOX-Remote-Controller-For-AndroidiOS-Cellphone-PC-p-1059243.html) :

or [this](http://www.hepsiburada.com/vr-box-bluetooth-kumanda-vr-glass-gamepad-oyun-kolu-p-HBV00000394A4?magaza=Probiel%20Bili%C5%9Fim&wt_gl=cpc.nelk.kultur.hobi.pla&gclid=Cj0KCQjwi97NBRD1ARIsAPXVWWBjuhNwLAV7HjP2cRawUR6BUTbV2ZH74egO9v31L-j4WdmHWTod1YkaAm7pEALw_wcB).

Can I use these bluetooth controllers with Unity? How can I map these controllers ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as you connect a bluetooth controller, it gets handled by the OS as a device. You then just need to find out which Key corresponds with which KeyCode.

For example, you could write something like this

```
public void detectPressedKeyOrButton()
 {
     foreach(KeyCode kcode in Enum.GetValues(typeof(KeyCode)))
     {
         if (Input.GetKeyDown(kcode))
             Debug.Log("KeyCode down: " + kcode);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! That's what I need.